# how to pass between two dates logic in filterFilter($scope.items, newVal)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<tr  ng-repeat="item in filtered = items |  filter:search  |startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
```

angular:
     Here 'today' condition working fine ,in  'last week' function i am getting exaxt results directly in 'newVal'. here my doubt is how to pass between Two dates condition in " `filterFilter($scope.items, newVal);`

```
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.totalItems = $scope.items.length;
$scope.entryLimit = 8; // items per page
$scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
$scope.$watch('search', function (newVal, oldVal) {

if(newVal.order_date=='today')
{ 
   var date= new Date();
   var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(date), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
   newVal.order_date=_date;
}
if(newVal.order_date=='lastweek')
{
    var today = new Date();
    var lastWeek = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);
    var lastWeekMonth = lastWeek.getMonth() + 1;
    var lastWeekDay = lastWeek.getDate();
    var lastWeekYear = lastWeek.getFullYear();
    var from = lastWeekMonth + "/" + lastWeekDay + "/" + lastWeekYear;
    var to = $filter('date')(new Date(today), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    var start_date = (from && !isNaN(Date.parse(from))) ? Date.parse(from) : 0;
    var end_date = (to && !isNaN(Date.parse(to))) ? Date.parse(to) : new Date().getTime();
    newVal= $filter('filter')($scope.items, 'order_date', function(v){
        var date = new Date(v);
        return date >= moment(start_date) && date <= moment(end_date);
    }); 
}
$scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.items, newVal);
$scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;     
$scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
$scope.currentPage = 1;
}, true);
```

Comment: I already made a working demo in `plunker` here http://plnkr.co/edit/OhHnLo3f523TjTbAoM8s?p=preview but what it is missing is your `filterFilter` service

Comment: @pryxen , i am new to angular. can u update plunker with that updated code for lastweek . don't know how to implement 'filterFilter'  service to lastweek.

Comment: where is your plunker @suresh?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/OhHnLo3f523TjTbAoM8s?p=preview  , created by you @pryxen , this  code only  i did , can u update in this plunker?

Comment: then why did you use the `filterFilter` if you don't have that service?

Comment: i solved  this issue  with custom filters . thanks for quick reply @pryxen

Comment: I'm glad you already solved this issue :)